# UICollectionView shows wrong number of items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a UICollectionView to display a horizontally scrollable list of items. Unfortunately this is not working the way I expect it - specifically it displays the wrong number of items.

My data source for the collection view is a simple NSArray of NSStrings and my UICollectionViewDataSource methods look like this:

```
    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSMutableArray *tagNames = self.tags;

    return tagNames.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *tagNames = self.tags;
    TokenCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kTokenCellID
                                                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *associatedTagName = [tagNames objectAtIndexedSubscript:indexPath.item];

    //configure cell...

    return cell;
}
```

However the UICollectionView is displaying exactly one less item then what is returned from numberOfItemsInSection.

I would be happy about any advice regarding this issue and how to solve it!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit as requested by posted comments**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //smaller font size
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] }
                                                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}
```

Data source (populated for testing):

```
self.tags = @[@"First Tag", @"Second Tag", @"Third Tag", @"Fourth Tag", @"Fith Tag"];
```

Comment: post your viewDidload method and the code where you populating tags array

Comment: I don't think this will fix your problem, but there's no need to create tagNames the way you do; just use self.tags instead. Which item is not being displayed? The last one? If you make your array contain only 4 items, does it display all 4 or only 3?

Comment: It cuts of the last item, however only if their are more items then the maximum number of items that can fit on screen...

Comment: So e.g. if I have only two items both will be displayed.

Comment: So, do you have scrolling enabled? Can you not scroll to see that last item?

Comment: That's the odd thing about it... Sometimes it will just be not their. But sometimes I am able to scroll to it however to reveal it I have to hold my finger down - if I let go the collection view automatically scrolls back to the previous item...

Comment: How are you setting the size of the cells?

Comment: I am using self-sizing cells. Basically I set up the constraints in the cell plus setting the estimatedItemSize to a non-zero value, which is working really well.

Comment: I think that maybe it isn't working "really well". At least with table views, one problem with using self-sizing cells is that the content size of the scroll view isn't always correct, I suspect that's the same problem you're having here. Try returning larger sizes for the estimated size, and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: You're right! setting the size to something bigger does show all cells! Thanks a lot! How ever this introduces other difficulties, I'll have to experiment we the size I specify their. Anyway thanks again, for pointing that out... I was trusting apple to provide a working solution however that might be something that you should not do.